# Rendering crash with new gpu (rtx 2070 super)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

So I changed my graphics card from gtx 1060 6gb to rtx 2070 8gb super.

I have the exactly same scene and options. I'm start rendering and after 30min or sometimes less blender randomly close itself without any error message. If I do something else on the pc it's closing way earlier like in a few minutes.

I'm rendering with cycles, I tried with CUDA and Optix.
I checked the temperature of the card with multiple software and it was max 65 degrees Celsius. Though it felt way hotter when I removed it.

I have only 8gb ram what could be the case, but it never crashed with my old card so I don't understand.

If I put back the old card back still never crash, I have no idea what is the problem with my new card, please if you have any idea share with me, thank you.

Comment: Check that you've got all the drivers updated

Comment: Start you renders from cmd so you can get error messages